# How to find the iOS simulator folder

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm looking for the specific location in the filesystem where the iOS simulators are stored that Xcode downloads for you. I've been looking in the usual locations like `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs` or `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator` but no luck.

Does anyone know the specific location that they're downloaded into?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are installed to `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` *(Not `~/Library`!)*

Comment: Seems to be outdated

Comment: Nope.  This is not outdated.  This is where we still install the DLC simulator runtimes.  CoreSimualtor looks inside of Xcode.app, /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes, and ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes for runtimes.